# Will this code adjust its alignments automatically with respect to the user's screen?

Tags: html, beginner, css

**HTML**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome To DPS Raipur</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.gif" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
            <div class="title" id="title"><img class="dps_logo" id="dps_logo" src="dps_logo.jpg" alt="DPS Logo" title="DPS Logo" /></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper 
{
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    width: 1200px; 
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.title
{
    background-color: #06472F;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

This is a website I am creating and I am completely a beginner, so I don't know whether this code will adjust its alignments automatically with respect to the user's screen. What should I do to make it like that? How can it be improved?

Also, I've been asked to create this site and I don't know how to put a site online. So, will it be OK if I keep all the web pages on my computer by in various folders?

Comment: have you done any searching for what you are asking here?  this Question smells of "Off-Topic" for Code Review.

Comment: I asked whether the code I have written will adjust itself according to the user's screen's resolution.

Comment: Why don't you simply say: sorry. I can't make that ;) I think it is best you read some tutorials on html and start from there

Comment: Just an FYI: I **have** read some tutorials. And that's the only thing I am struggling with. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

the code will auto align to the user's browser window, as long as the browser window is greater than `1200px`

**Second Question**

if you keep the files on your computer they will not be online, you have to host the pages on a web server and obtain a Domain name and all sorts of other stuff pertaining to attaching that site to the Domain Name and DNS Servers and such.

most of the time they will give you a root directory and as long as you keep the file structure the same you shouldn't have to change the links, you should look into `absolute pathing` and because I could be wrong, I usually have to check to make sure that I set my links right,  but I am pretty sure that your graphics should show up if they are in the root folder of the site with out having to change the links.

personally I would recommend that you create a folder called `images` or `pictures` or `graphics`  something to that effect, and change the links to `images/logo.gif` same with your StyleSheets those should as well be in their own folder, I usally name my CSS folder `CSS`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though, I know that they won't go online just by keeping them on my computer. I wanted to know whether it'll be OK if I keep all the web pages on my computer and link the images and hyperlinks to a folder in my computer. Then when we upload the home page with all the folders, will it accept the directory or I need to put **all** the pages online and change the links like this:

website.com/path?

Comment: P.S. By "align itself" do you mean that if the website is viewed in a larger resolution, say 2048 X 1152, will it be displayed as same as it would in a resolution of 1024px or will the user need to zoom-in in order fit it with respect to its screen?

Comment: your content will only take up `1200px` and the left and right margins are set to auto, so any extra space on the sides will be margin, it will automatically center the content in the middle of the screen (horizontally).

Comment: OK, again, thanks a lot. Also, I am thinking about creating folders with names like: "about us" "our things" which will be accessed through the home page and the all the stylesheets used will be inside these folders.

Comment: just make sure that you check out file paths.  if you have a a page that is in a folder and you want to link to something else in that folder I don't think you need to preface it with the folder that the page is in.  does that make sense?

Comment: I think so. LOL. But I know what I have to do now, so, thanks. :)